# Adding new columns from row list as boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

My dataset looks like this (simplied):

```
+----+------+-------------------------------+
| ID | Name |            Options            |
+----+------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | John | {Sofa,Fridge,Pets,TV}         |
|  2 | Mary | {TV,Sofa,Fridge,Parking}      |
|  3 | Bob  | {TV,Sofa,Parking,Pets,Fridge} |
|  4 | Todd | {TV,Sofa,Fridge,Pets,AC}      |
+----+------+-------------------------------+
```

My expected output

```
+----+------+----+------+--------+---------+------+----+
| ID | Name | TV | Sofa | Fridge | Parking | Pets | AC |
+----+------+----+------+--------+---------+------+----+
|  1 | John |  1 |    1 |      1 |       0 |    1 |  0 |
|  2 | Mary |  1 |    1 |      1 |       1 |    0 |  0 |
|  3 | Bob  |  1 |    1 |      1 |       1 |    1 |  0 |
|  4 | Todd |  1 |    1 |      1 |       0 |    1 |  1 |
+----+------+----+------+--------+---------+------+----+
```

My Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("max_columns", None)
listings = pd.read_csv("../listings.csv")
final_list = list(map(lambda val:val.replace("{","").replace("}","") , listings['amenities'])) 
final_list_1 = ""

for values in final_list:
    final_list_1 += "," + values

final_list_2 = final_list_1.split(',')
print(list(set(final_list_2))[1:])
```

With above output I am able to get each unique value in that column like

```
['TV','Sofa','Fridge','Pets','AC','Parking']
```

From here on my attempt is to run a `for` loop and check if the values are available in the row or not and subsequently put true(1) or false(0).
 I have about 50 such options, so 50 new columns. This does look like pivot but there's no aggregation.

However, I am not sure how to *convert these list values inside a row value to their respective new column as boolean* in pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset
data = [[1, "John", "{Sofa,Fridge,Pets,TV}"],
        [1, "Mary", "{TV,Sofa,Fridge,Parking}"],
        [1, "Bob", "{TV,Sofa,Parking,Pets,Fridge}"],
        [1, "Todd", "{TV,Sofa,Fridge,Pets,AC}"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "Name", "Options"])

# Replace curly brackets
df.Options = df.Options.str.replace("{","").str.replace("}","")

# Extract amenities per row and their unique values (these will be our new colums)
options_per_row = df.Options.str.split(',').tolist()
unique_values = np.unique(np.concatenate(options_per_row))

# We don't need "Options" column anymore
df = df.drop('Options', axis=1)

# Use list comprehension to combine each row's "options" with unique_values list - results in table of 0's and 1's
binarised = [[1 if unique in el else 0 for unique in unique_values] for el in options_per_row]
# Make it a dataframe to easily concatenate with the original dataframe
binarised_df = pd.DataFrame(binarised, columns=unique_values)

# Concatenate columns together.
result = pd.concat([df, binarised_df], axis=1)

print(result)
```

Produces:

```
   ID  Name  AC  Fridge  Parking  Pets  Sofa  TV
0   1  John   0       1        0     1     1   1
1   1  Mary   0       1        1     0     1   1
2   1   Bob   0       1        1     1     1   1
3   1  Todd   1       1        0     1     1   1
```

You will have to fiddle with the code if the order of columns somehow matters but that's the gist.

EDIT:

To explain further - the list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
binarised = []
for options in options_per_row:
    binarised_row = []
    for unique in unique_values:
        if unique in options:
            binarised_row.append(1)
        else:
            binarised_row.append(0)
    binarised.append(binarised_row)
```

and in this case as an intermediate result produces:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

which then becomes `binarised_df`:

```
   AC  Fridge  Parking  Pets  Sofa  TV
0   0       1        0     1     1   1
1   0       1        1     0     1   1
2   0       1        1     1     1   1
3   1       1        0     1     1   1
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation part. It was indeed helpful in understanding the code!